# What is the probability or percentage or frequency by which hello line will be printed?

Tags: probability, random, percentages

I have a below method which is called every one minute from background thread and that background thread keeps running always.

```
public void testMethod() {
    // some other code      
    int value = new Random().nextInt(20 - 1 + 1) + 1;
    if(value > 19) {
        // this will print hello line
        System.out.println("hello");        
    }       
    // some other code
}
```

Now as you can see I am printing `hello` if my value is greater than 19. My question is how should I say that `hello` line will be printed at this rate or it will printed this percentage of time so that people can understand this.

If somebody asks me at what frequency or rate `hello` line will be printed given my above method is called every 1 minute. What should I say?

This line `int value = new Random().nextInt(20 - 1 + 1) + 1;` will generate random number between $1$ and $20$ inclusive both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In every minute the probability that it will print `hello` is $\frac{1}{20}$ assuming that the "Random" is fair in JAVA

Let $A$ denote the event that it will print `hello` per one minute so $\mathrm {P}[A]=\frac{|A|}{|\Omega|}=\frac{1}{20}$

Therfore the rate is one `hello` per $20$ minutes

Comment: Got it now. So let's say if instead of `1` minute my `testMethod` is called every `30` seconds, then what will be the rate with same random formula?

Comment: If it will be every `30` sec so the probabilty for one `hello` per `30` sec will be $\frac{1}{20}$

Comment: Still $1/20$? What rate will be then?

Comment: then it will be one `hello` per $10$ minutes, because let's take the same event $A$ as before so now $A=1+1=2\Longrightarrow P[A]=\frac{2}{20}=1/10$

Answer (score 2):

Isn't the frequency just once per 20 minutes? 
"Hello" is printed only when the number is 20. That is with 1/20 probability. So, even if the rate varies each time, over an average of 7 hours, by 5% error margin, you can say the rate is 1 "hello" per 20 minutes.

Comment: Understood. So let's say if instead of $1$ minute my testMethod` is called every $30$ seconds, then what will be the rate with same random formula and what I will say then?

Comment: The rate will be halved..... I mean to say it will be 1 "hello" per 10 minutes. Probability will remain 1/20.

Comment: Can you add some explanation how it will be 1 per 10 minutes in this case?

Comment: probability = 1/20 => it occurs once in every 20 times on an average. If your method is called every 30 seconds, It takes 10 minutes to call your method 20 times. So, in 10 minutes, you get a "hello" printed. I hope this helps.